# How to safely calibrate a step-up DC-DC converter?

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter

I have a simple DC-DC step-up converter. For example [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32948417810.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.519c47c0uOGC9u&algo_pvid=3d21ffc9-bc50-42b2-85b5-ba35096f42e2&algo_exp_id=3d21ffc9-bc50-42b2-85b5-ba35096f42e2-3&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000015705863453%22%7D).
It has a potentiometer and I need to rotate it using a screwdriver to change voltage. How do I safely adjust output voltage without connecting it to my main circuit?
As far as I know, I need a power supply, for example, [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000205497886.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.3b672978mLVM7M&algo_pvid=0d1e75d0-727e-447a-9c9c-5bb014617d50&algo_exp_id=0d1e75d0-727e-447a-9c9c-5bb014617d50-7&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000000786521008%22%7D).
But what is the circuit? The power supply has 2 wires, they go to inputs of the step-up converter. But what should I connect to the outputs of the step-up converter? Can I connect a simple multimeter I have, similar to [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000991575808.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.6e4c534ee86nDZ&algo_pvid=3f29b45f-5608-48da-accd-c6522c0b7d75&algo_exp_id=3f29b45f-5608-48da-accd-c6522c0b7d75-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000025669496137%22%7D)?
I'm not sure if I can connect this multimeter in a series (not parallel). Also, I'm not sure that electronic probes are suitable for connection in a series. Should I use alligators instead? Or maybe something else? Or maybe it's better to make a wire between two outputs of the step-up converter? Won't it cause a short circuit?
But again, my question is how to safely calibrate the DC-DC step-up converter? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: it appears that you should be asking about the use of a multimeter for obtaining measurements before you start calibrating anything

Answer (score 2):

Voltage doesn't flow, but current does.

A multi-meter in voltage measurement mode is high resistance between the terminals so not short circuit. It is sampling the way you would sample wine from a barrel: you take and test just a tiny little drop. So not much current is drawn. It takes just a tiny bit of current in order to measure the voltage.

However, a multi-meter in current measurement mode *will* short-circuit since it is low resistance between the terminals there the same way you might measure water flow. No point measuring the flow of something if you just end up blocking it all with your measurement device.

If you hook up your multi-meter as if you were measuring voltage but it is in current measurement mode, that is a short-circuit and it will blow.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131467/discussion-on-answer-by-dknguyen-how-to-safely-calibrate-a-step-up-dc-dc-convert).